# How to Synchronize request inside servlet action

Tags: java, multithreading, struts

I have a servlet action method.If one request comes and try to do something. And if there is a second request I want to block it till first one completes.How i can achieve that.?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a standard Java `synchronized` block to achieve this. Something like this:

```
synchronized(this) {
  // do some stuff
}
```

However I strongly recommend to don't do something like this in a servlet because it may lead to serious performance impacts. Servlets should be stateless and therefore concurrent requests shouldn't effect each other.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. If your user base is limited and not growing it is recommended your servlet implements the `SingleThreadModel` interface. This makes sure that only one request is processed at a time by the servlet.
2. If your user base is growing and you need to scale, it is recommended to use the `synchronization block`. Here you will only synchronize that 'code block' which may cause ambiguity in your data. The idea is to reduce the amount of code that is to be synchronized so that it doesn't cause any performance issues.